# C/C++ global variable uniqueness?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, global-variables

Consider the following:

```
// defs.h
extern "C" {

    typedef struct t_state
    {
        bool b;
    } t_state;

    static t_state _state;

    void t_state_allocate();
}

// defs.cpp

#include "defs.h"
void t_state_allocate()
{
    _state.b = true;
    printf("G state at %p is %d\n", &_state, _state.b);
}

// App.hpp

#include "defs.h"
class App
{
    App();
};

// App.cpp

#include "App.hpp"
App::App()
{
    printf("1 state at %p is %d\n", &_state, _state.b)
    t_state_allocate();
    printf("2 state at %p is %d\n", &_state, _state.b)
}
```

Output under G++ is something like:

> 1 state at 0x736e20 is 0
>
> G state at 0x9cb140 is 1
>
> 2 state at 0x736e20 is 0

Here the expected behaviour is to access the same structure.. Where's the mistake ?

#### EDIT 1

`t_state` must be a pure C `struct` because it is used in other `.c` source code (and thus the `extern` keyword). However I can grant that *nobody* modifies its content.

Comment: You're a) defining a variable in a header file, and b) defining it to be static - which most probably wouldn't do what you'd expect. Instead, define it in exactly one C source file, and declare it as `extern` in the `.hpp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have two **different** global variables: one at App.cpp including defs.h, and the other one at defs.cpp including defs.h.

You have to use `extern` as you can see here:

[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Answer (score 1):

defs.h is included twice in two different .cpp files. so there are two instances of `_state` getting created. This is because `#include` essentially pastes the contents of the header into the file that includes it. So how do you get around this problem? Use `extern`:

```
typedef struct t_state
{
   bool b;
} t_state;

extern t_state _state; //Tells the compiler to share the variable between files.
```

Now you can use the variable in each source file:

```
#include "defs.h"
void t_state_allocate()
{
   _state.b = true;
   printf("G state at %p is %d\n", &_state, _state.b);
}
```